# Is there a way to launch several node tasks in a specific order?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I've created a kind of framework that is a bit tedious to install right now. It needs 4 user inputs before actually starting to work and I want to reduce it to only one input.

Basically I'm just trying to know if there is a way to launch those 4 commands with only 1 input, but not all at the same time! Each task must wait the end of the previous task. My node.js knowledge is not good so I didn't really know how to find an anwser efficiently on google.

```
$npm install
$bower install
$gulp task1
$gulp task2
```

Comment: Create a shell script? And a `.bat` file for those on Windows stuck without a bash shell?

Comment: Those are not Node commands so it isn't very surprising that Google searches turn out empty.

Comment: hum yeah I guess it was a stupid comment from myself then. I've never created a batch file before, but I'm going to look in that direction

Comment: well for now I only managed to create a batch that launch the 4 commands each simultaneously, in 4 different cmd.exe .. not really great

Answer (score 0):

ok, then I made this bat file, which works :

```
@ECHO off
ECHO Program name 
ECHO Press any key...
PAUSE > nul
CALL task1
CALL task2
CALL task3
CALL task4
PAUSE
```

thanks